# Remove unique row from csv

Tags: excel, csv

I have a csv with the following structure:

```
Source  Target  LinkId  LinkName    Throughput
==================================================
1       12      1250     link1250           5
1       12      3250     link3250           14
1       14      1250     link1250           5
1       14      3250     link3250           14
1       18      1250     link1250           5
1       18      3250     link3250           14
1       25      250      link250             24 //to be removed
2       12      2250     link2250           5
2       12      5250     link5250           14
2       14      2250     link2250           5
2       14      5250     link5250           14
2       18      2250     link2250           5
2       18      5250     link5250           14
2       58      50       link50             34 //to be removed
```

In the above csv, I am supposed to removed rows that are occurring only once, like the ones highlighted above. In the highlighted row, there is only one row existing for link 250. I was wondering if there is an easy way to do this using excel.

Comment: Do you need to do this in a continuous fashion or just once to "fix" your data?

Comment: I need to do it in a continuous fashion @UlliSchmid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) "Quick Fix" Approach - helper column and filter**

Create a new column F "Occurances". In F3, enter

```
=COUNTIF(D:D,D3)
```

Then copy cell F3 to F4:F16. Now you can simply filter everything that only has one occurance:

- Select your whole range (A1:F16, including column F and row 1)
- Click Data -> Filter
- Click Occurance(F1) -> unselect "1" to filter the unwanted rows

**2) "Continuous Fix" - helper column and Index/Match**

Create a new column F "Helper". In F3, enter

```
=F2+(COUNTIF(D:D,D3)<>1)
```

Then copy cell F3 to F4:F16. You can now create a "cleaned" or filtered sheet of your data:

- Create a new Excel Worksheet (Sheet2, I assume the old one is named Sheet1)
- Copy your headers (A1:E2) from Sheet1
- Into A3, enter `=INDEX(Sheet1!A$3:F$16,MATCH(ROW()-2,Sheet1!$F$3:$F$16,0),1)`
- Copy A3 to A3:E14

Sheet2 will now automatically create a filtered copy of Sheet1.

Comment: I forgot to mention in my question that the csv has more than 5k rows and more than 150 sources.